# Duplicate records validation when inserting new record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I would like to know what is the best practice of doing duplicate check as inserting new records.
For instance, I have an entity with a list property reference to another entity. For instance,

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public virtual List<ClassB> subObjects{ set; get; } = new();
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
}
```

The rule is to make sure all properties equal to be validated as duplicate.
My approach is similiar as below to validate and insert the newRecord.

```
var objects = await _repositoryManager.ClassARepository.FindByCondition(x => x.Name == newRecord.Name && x.Description == newRecord.Description); 

var objectList = objects.Include(t => t.subObjects).ToList();

foreach (var object in objectList)
{
    if (newRecord.SubObjectIds.SequenceEqual(object.subObjects.Select(x => x.Id)))
    {
        throw new ValidationException(DUPLICATE_DATA_ERROR);
    }
}
// To insert the new record here
```

Any better ways or best practice?

Any advice or answers would be highly apprecaited.